# Python : Extract values of 1 day from a dictionnary with datetime as keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with a datetime as key and a number as value.

```
dict = {datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 8, 1 ,15, 3):3, datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 8, 8 ,15, 8):4,
        datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 9, 7 ,15, 0):4 , datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 9, 10 ,30, 0):8}
```

I want this result:

```
result = {datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 9, 07 ,15, 0):4 , datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 9, 10 ,30, 0):8}
```

or

```
result = [4, 8]
```

I edited my dict. Before it was string keys and values:

```
dict = {'08/07/2015 01:15':'3', '08/07/2015 08:15':'5',
           '09/07/2015 07:15':'4', '09/07/2015 10:30':'8'}
```

Comment: Your keys are strings, not [`datetime.datetime` objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime). If you meant that they were actually `datetime` objects, please adjust your question accordingly.

Comment: I ajusted my question. I changed with datetime.

Comment: Don't use `07`, that's an octal number. Remove the leading `0`.

Comment: And I already answered your new version, but take into account that altering your question this radically is frowned upon, as people already put in work answering the original version. Try to think about your question before posting some more.

Comment: Yes it is for that I put my old version also at the end of the question. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply iterate over your keys and find matches:

```
def extract(data, day):
    return {key: data[key] for key in data if day in key}

dict = {'08/07/2015 01:15':'3', '08/07/2015 08:15':'5',
        '09/07/2015 07:15':'4', '09/07/2015 10:30':'8'}

print extract(dict, '09/07/2015')
{'09/07/2015 07:15': '4', '09/07/2015 10:30': '8'}
```

second output can be achieved analogously

```
def extract(data, day):
    return [data[key] for key in data if day in key]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your keys are strings, just loop and match the string:

```
{key: value for key, value in dict.items() if key.startswith('09/07/2015')}
```

or to get just the values:

```
[value for key, value in dict.items() if key.startswith('09/07/2015')]
```

If you really have [`datetime.datetime()` objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime), you can match the output of the [`datetime.date()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date) against a [`datetime.date` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date):

```
from datetime import date

[value for key, value in dict.items() if key.date() == date(2015, 7, 9)]
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: not in the sample they are not. They are *strings*, and the user is only using the same word as a built-in type.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't mean they are talking about the *type*. They could also talk about the *concept*. Besides, they gave sample input and expected output, *both using strings*.

Comment: I also note that they tagged the question as `numpy`, but I don't see anything specific to numpy either.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in several ways but the key is to work with the date. Transform that string into a datetime object first using strptime (https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) then, you can get your unique days by transforming back with strftime with the appropriate format. 
Finally, you can search in your keys with "in" using the parsed days.